# What is the probability $X+Y=0$ for two independent Poisson random variables?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, poisson-distribution

For two independent Poisson random variables, $X$ and $Y$, with parameters $\lambda_1 > 0$ and $\lambda_2>0$ respectively, how do I find P$\{X+Y=0\}$ in terms of $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: a sum of independent Poisson variables with parameters $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ is a Poisson variable with parameter $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  $X+Y = 0$ if and only if $X = 0$ and $Y = 0$.

Comment: And if I want to find P$\{X+Y=1\}$?

Comment: You could do it the hard way and write $$\Pr[X+Y = 1] = \Pr[X=0]\Pr[Y=1] + \Pr[X=1]\Pr[Y=0],$$ or you could use Hugo's hint.

Comment: Why does that work? Don't many more numbers add up to 1, like $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: A Poisson random variable cannot be $1/2$:  it is a discrete random variable that can only take on the values $0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots$.

Comment: Some advice for you:  the level of detail of the responses you will get from this site, and from me in particular, would be greater if you show more effort on your part, rather than simply asking questions and expecting answers.

Comment: Thanks for your help, and I will take your advice to heart.